# Open program with a script

Tags: bash, scripting, freebsd

I need some help. How do I run a command in a shorter way. Let me try and explain. I have openVPN install on a headless system. If I want to disable it I have to /usr/local/etc.... stop. Can I write like a script in the root directory called lets say "OpenVPN stop" and then it runs the /usr/local/etc/... command?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: do you mean creating aliases ? please reffer https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases . you can do something line alias ll="ls -la" and then use ll as a shortcut for long command

Comment: You could add the directory containing openVPN to your PATH.

Comment: bash is not the native shell on FreeBSD--just to be sure you're aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please reffer [link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases)  .
   You can do something like `alias ll="ls -la"`  and then use `ll` as a shortcut for long command

[image]

2. alias need to be defined before you start your script in ~/.bashrc
   otherwise you may get "command not found" error
3. define functions and use them

```
fn_vpns () { /usr/local/rc.d/openvpn start }
fn_vpns
```

Comment: I tried that. My command is as follows: 'alias OpenVPN_Start="/usr/local/rc.d/openvpn start"' when I type OpenVPN_Start it comes back with "OpenVPN_Start: Command not found"

Comment: add your command to  ~/.bashrc  and re-log in

Comment: or use functions
fn_vpns () { /usr/local/rc.d/openvpn start }
fn_vpns

Comment: Are you aware that bash is not native to FreeBSD and must be installed and config'ed to use?

Comment: 1) no 2) bash is in the tags 3) last option functions may also work, just add definition to the start up script

Answer (score 1):

you can create bash alias. Example:

```sh
alias OpenVPN="/usr/local/etc/... $1"
```

Where `$1` is the placeholder for the argument you give after `OpenVPN` command

Comment: Are you aware that bash is not native to FreeBSD and must be installed and config'ed to use?

Comment: never used FreeBSD but `bash` is included in the tags so I'm assuming the person who asked the question is using it as the main shell and I based my answer on that